# Text overflow outside of a box, using React and Flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am having some trouble with the layout in a React web app of mine.
Though it mostly work as I want, here is the situation.

This is the relevant React code:

```
<React.Fragment>
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-xl-12-w">
      <h1 className='blocTit'>{displayTitle}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-xl-12-w">
      {clctnBufr.map((item,index) => (
        <div
          key={item.uid}
          className="card float-left"
          style={{ width: "18rem", marginRight: "1rem" }}
        >
          <div className="card-body">
            <div className="card-tit-prx">
              <div className="card-title">
                {displayName(item)}
              </div>
              <div className="card-price">
                {displayPriceC(item.price,this.priceShft,currency)}
              </div>
            </div>
            {displayComment(item)}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</React.Fragment>
```

And this is what I believe to be the relevant css code:

```
.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid rgb(117, 61, 5);
  background-color: rgb(228, 245, 131);
  padding-block: 5px;
}

.card-tit-prx {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-self: stretch;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.card-title {
  color: rgb(52, 8, 155);
  font-family: 'Georgia';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.card-price {
  color: rgb(185, 73, 28);
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

The image below is a screenshot showing the issue on the last 3 items where part of the text (namely: "spring onion", "meet") is overflowing outside of the box instead of being inside as the rest of the text.

[image]

I have also unsuccessfully tried to reproduce the issue outside of the context. So I wonder if I am not missing something. If someone has an idea on how to further investigate or even better solve this problem I'd be glad.

Here is some more information. By inserting a space in the display of the price (see the 2nd screenshot below) it makes it take 2 lines and the box gets a proper size as consequence. Why it did not get this size when the name (left part) was requiring it is a mystery.

But I do not want to have to insert a space in the display of the price! This is the problem.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to put the comment inside an element

Comment: displayComment is in fact putting the comment inside a div element, when a comment is present, it returns null otherwise. But this problem appears when the left part ("card-title") is long, whether there is a comment or not.

Comment: For some reasons that I do not know the box height seems (according to some testing I did) to adjust well  on the length of the right part ("card-price") but not on the left part.

Comment: If so, can't we use height: max-content for card-body

Comment: I'll try that. But I still can't understand why the box seems to ignore the contents of the card-title part while perfectly following the card-price part, accor ding to some tests I did.

Comment: How about using float-left instead of display:inline-block?

Comment: @kangminki. I don't know much about float-left and display:inline-block. I always try to use flexbox. And most of the time I find it convenient. Here I am hitting a problem though. I'd like to know why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue after spending some time digging.

Just in case somebody happens to read this while hitting a similar case, I report what I did.

The problem of the *"card-title"* part and the *"card-price"* part not exhibiting the same behavior for some mysterious reason came from the fact that *"card-title"* was already defined in a different .css file. The two definitions were conflicting and producing the problem. It was difficult to see at first glance because this other .css file was not directly included and I am not so familiar with the workings of CSS.

A lesson seems to be: **"It is not a good idea to define the same css item in two or more different places in a project"**.